# android weather app cant display the received data(forecast) on the screen

Tags: android, json

i have developed android weather app that receives data from forecast weather site, i have a problem in casting the Relativelayout i cant figure it out,
here is my code :

Mainactivity.java

```
package synctc.me.stormy;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
   private CurrentWeather mCurrentWeather ;


    @InjectView(R.id.timeLabel) TextView mTimeLabel;
    @InjectView(R.id.temperatureLabel) TextView mTemperatureLabel;
    @InjectView(R.id.humidityValue) TextView mHumidityValue;
    @InjectView(R.id.precipValue) TextView mPrecipValue;
    @InjectView(R.id.summaryLabel) RelativeLayout mSummaryLabel;
    @InjectView(R.id.iconImageView) ImageView mIconImageView;
    @InjectView(R.id.refreshImageView) ImageView mRefreshImageView;
    @InjectView(R.id.progressBar)ProgressBar mProgressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final double latitude = 37.8267;
        final double longitude = -122.423;
        mRefreshImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getForecast(latitude,longitude);
            }
        });


        getForecast(latitude,longitude);

            Log.d(TAG, "Main ui is running");
    }

    private void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude) {
        String apiKey="37ee485ed1ec27026ef5ff8948b6f94b";
        String forecastUrl="https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"+apiKey+"/"+latitude+","+longitude;
        if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(forecastUrl)
                .build();
        Call call=client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleRefresh();
                    }
                });
                alertUserAboutError();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     toggleRefresh();
                 }
             });
                try {
                      String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                     mCurrentWeather = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateDisplay();
                            }
                        });

                    }else{
                     alertUserAboutError();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught : ",e);

                }
                catch (JSONException e){

                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught : ",e);
                }

            }
        });}
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this
                    , getString(R.string.network_unavailable_messege)
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


    private void updateDisplay() {
        mTemperatureLabel.setText(mCurrentWeather.getTemperature()+"");
        mTimeLabel.setText("At" +mCurrentWeather.getFormattedTime()+"it will be ");
        mHumidityValue.setText(mCurrentWeather.getHumidity()+"");
        mPrecipValue.setText(mCurrentWeather.getPrecipChane()+"%");

        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(mCurrentWeather.getIconId());
        mIconImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);


    }

    private CurrentWeather getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException{
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject (jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        Log.i(TAG,"From JSON To:"+timezone);
        JSONObject currently = new JSONObject("currently");
        CurrentWeather currentWeather = new CurrentWeather();
        currentWeather.setHumidity(currently.getDouble("humidity"));
        currentWeather.setTime(currently.getLong("time"));
        currentWeather.setIcon(currently.getString("icon"));
        currentWeather.setPrecipChane(currently.getDouble("precipProbability"));
        currentWeather.setSummery(currently.getString("summery"));
        currentWeather.setTemperature(currently.getDouble("temperature"));
        currentWeather.setTimeZone(timezone);
        Log.d(TAG, currentWeather.getFormattedTime());
        return  currentWeather;
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

        toggleRefresh();


        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if(networkInfo != null &&networkInfo.isConnected()){
            isAvailable=true ;

        }
        return  isAvailable;

    }

    private void toggleRefresh() {
        if(mProgressBar.getVisibility()== View.INVISIBLE) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");

    }
}
```

//AlertDialogFragment.java

```
package synctc.me.stormy;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Context context = getActivity();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.error_title))
                .setMessage(context.getString(R.string.error_messege))
                .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.error_ok_button_text), null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

//CurrentWeather.java

```
package synctc.me.stormy;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class CurrentWeather {
   private String mIcon;
    private long  mTime;
    private double mTemperature;
    private double mHumidity;

    public String getTimeZone() {
        return mTimeZone;
    }

    public void setTimeZone(String timeZone) {
        mTimeZone = timeZone;
    }

    private double mPrecipChane;
    private String mSummery;
    private String mTimeZone;

    public String getIcon() {
        return mIcon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        mIcon = icon;
    }
    public int getIconId(){
        int iconId = R.mipmap.clear_day;
        if (mIcon.equals("clear-day")) {
            iconId = R.mipmap.clear_day;
        }
        else if (mIcon.equals("clear-night")) {
            iconId = R.mipmap.clear_night;
        }
        else if (mIcon.equals("rain")) {
            iconId = R.mipmap.rain;
        }
        else if (mIcon.equals("snow")) {
            iconId = R.mipmap.snow;
        }
        else if (mIcon.equals("sleet")) {
            iconId = R.mipmap.sleet;
        }
        else if (mIcon.equals("wind")) {
            iconId = R.mipmap.wind;
        }
        else if (mIcon.equals("fog")) {
            iconId = R.mipmap.fog;
        }
        else if (mIcon.equals("cloudy")) {
            iconId = R.mipmap.cloudy;
        }
        else if (mIcon.equals("partly-cloudy-day")) {
            iconId = R.mipmap.partly_cloudy;
        }
        else if (mIcon.equals("partly-cloudy-night")) {
            iconId = R.mipmap.cloudy_night;
        }

        return iconId;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return mTime;
    }

    public String getFormattedTime(){
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(getTimeZone()));
        Date datetime = new Date(getTime()*1000);
        String timeString = formatter.format(datetime);
        return timeString;

    }


    public void setTime(long time) {
        mTime = time;
    }

    public int getTemperature() {
        return(int)  Math.round(mTemperature);
    }

    public void setTemperature(double temperature) {
        mTemperature = temperature;
    }

    public double getHumidity() {
        return mHumidity;
    }

    public void setHumidity(double humidity) {
        mHumidity = humidity;
    }

    public String getSummery() {
        return mSummery;
    }

    public void setSummery(String summery) {
        mSummery = summery;
    }

    public int getPrecipChane() {
        double precipPercentage = mPrecipChane * 100;
        return (int)Math.round(precipPercentage) ;
    }

    public void setPrecipChane(double precipChane) {
        mPrecipChane = precipChane;
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
03-29 06:32:43.596    1779-1797/synctc.me.stormy E/MainActivity﹕ Exception Caught :
    org.json.JSONException: Value currently of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
            at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
            at synctc.me.stormy.MainActivity.getCurrentDetails(MainActivity.java:153)
            at synctc.me.stormy.MainActivity.access$400(MainActivity.java:37)
            at synctc.me.stormy.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:106)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:162)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-29 06:33:01.383    1838-1838/synctc.me.stormy D/MainActivity﹕ Main ui is running
03-29 06:33:01.399    1838-1859/synctc.me.stormy D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
03-29 06:33:01.474    1838-1838/synctc.me.stormy D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xabb93d20, tid 1838
03-29 06:33:01.529    1838-1838/synctc.me.stormy D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
03-29 06:33:01.647    1838-1859/synctc.me.stormy D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-29 06:33:01.648    1838-1859/synctc.me.stormy D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-29 06:33:01.665    1838-1859/synctc.me.stormy D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-29 06:33:01.687    1838-1859/synctc.me.stormy D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa3216120, tid 1859
03-29 06:33:01.718    1838-1859/synctc.me.stormy I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-29 06:33:01.843    1838-1859/synctc.me.stormy D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-29 06:33:01.899    1838-1859/synctc.me.stormy W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-29 06:33:01.899    1838-1859/synctc.me.stormy W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa32192a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-29 06:33:02.849    1838-1858/synctc.me.stormy V/MainActivity﹕ {"latitude":37.8267,"longitude":-122.423,"timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","offset":-7,"currently":{"time":1427625186,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","nearestStormDistance":61,"nearestStormBearing":104,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":52.49,"apparentTemperature":52.49,"dewPoint":48.34,"humidity":0.86,"windSpeed":4.19,"windBearing":299,"visibility":6.15,"cloudCover":0.02,"pressure":1019.36,"ozone":330.14},"minutely":{"summary":"Clear for the hour.","icon":"clear-night","data":[{"time":1427625180,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625240,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625300,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625360,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625420,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625480,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625540,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625600,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625660,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625720,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625780,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625840,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625900,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427625960,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626020,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626080,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626140,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626200,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626260,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626320,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626380,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626440,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626500,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626560,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626620,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626680,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626740,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626800,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626860,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626920,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427626980,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627040,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627100,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627160,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627220,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627280,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627340,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627400,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627460,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627520,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627580,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627640,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627700,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627760,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627820,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627880,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427627940,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427628000,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427628060,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427628120,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427628180,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427628240,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427628300,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427628360,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427628420,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427628480,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1427628540,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":142762860
03-29 06:33:02.859    1838-1858/synctc.me.stormy I/MainActivity﹕ From JSON To:America/Los_Angeles
03-29 06:33:02.873    1838-1858/synctc.me.stormy E/MainActivity﹕ Exception Caught :
    org.json.JSONException: Value currently of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
            at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
            at synctc.me.stormy.MainActivity.getCurrentDetails(MainActivity.java:153)
            at synctc.me.stormy.MainActivity.access$400(MainActivity.java:37)
            at synctc.me.stormy.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:106)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:162)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MainActivity in getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) method the line having problem is below one:-

```
JSONObject currently = new JSONObject("currently");
```

The "currently" is just a string and your trying it to convert to json object which throwing error. "currently" is object in you jsonData String so

Instead of above line try below :-

```
 JSONObject currently = new JSONObject(forecast.get("currently").toString());
```